# How do I center the linear gradient animation as it zooms it?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to animate radial gradients by changing their background-positioning and the size of their elements. I've tried using flexbox to vertically and horizontally align .anim2 inside of .animcontain, as well as setting padding and margins, but nothing seems to be working. How do I go about zooming into the center of the radial gradient background without squishing it?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(80px, 20vmin));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, 20vmin);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}

.anim1 {
  animation: anim1 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background-size: 100% 3000%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    red,
    orange,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
    indigo,
    violet,
    indigo,
    blue,
    green,
    yellow,
    orange,
    red
  );
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 1000%;
    height: 1000%;
  }
}

.animcontain {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.anim2 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    red,
    orange,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
    indigo,
    violet
  );
  animation: anim2 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="align">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="anim1"></div>
      <div class="animcontain">
        <div class="anim2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="anim3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't animate width/height, animate the `background-size`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(80px, 20vmin));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, 20vmin);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}

.anim1 {
  animation: anim1 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background-size: 100% 3000%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    red,
    orange,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
    indigo,
    violet,
    indigo,
    blue,
    green,
    yellow,
    orange,
    red
  );
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  100% {
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  }
}

.animcontain {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    red,
    orange,
    yellow,
    green,
    blue,
    indigo,
    violet
  );
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position:center;
  animation: anim2 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="anim1"></div>
      <div class="animcontain">
      </div>
      <div class="anim3"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center anim2 you just have to add display grid with place-items center in animcontain class:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(80px, 20vmin));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, 20vmin);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container>div {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}

.anim1 {
  animation: anim1 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background-size: 100% 3000%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 1000%;
    height: 1000%;
  }
}

.animcontain {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.anim2 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
  animation: anim2 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="anim1"></div>
    <div class="animcontain">
      <div class="anim2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="anim3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```